# run a function multiple times without waiting for response in php

Tags: php, multithreading, asynchronous, sendasynchronousrequest, bulk-mail

I have a mailing function and 100k email ids. I want to call a function multiple times like 10 times and in each time it will process 10k emails. I want to call this function without waiting for response just call a function and another and another without getting response.

I tried pthread for multi threading but can't run it successfully.

I am using my sql database

Comment: you can try asynchronous ajax to run parallel

Comment: I am calling my php file using cron because mails are scheduled mails.for that how can i use ajax.. please explain

Comment: then you can not use ajax if you are using cron.

Comment: yes there is scheduled mails for a specific time for that I have to use cron ..

Comment: You can schedule multiple crons. But I am not sure if it affect performance speed

Comment: I tried this it affects performance of server.

Comment: Please don't use Indian words, especially ones that are misspelled into an English word. That can create a lot of confusion.

Comment: why you removed this line as this is also part of my question "I am using php please suggest me also for bulk mailing script php is suitable or I should move to any other language." explain ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple PHP processes for that, just like you can use multiple threads, there isn't much of a difference for PHP, as PHP is shared nothing.

You probably want to wait for it to finish and to notice any errors, but don't want to wait for completion before launching another process. [Amp](http://amphp.org/) is perfectly suited for such use cases. Its [`amphp/parallel`](https://github.com/amphp/parallel) package makes multi-processing easier than using PHP's native API.

You can find a [usage example in the repository](https://github.com/amphp/parallel/blob/6ed128f3e7125fc16b1dce9fbd8a09855118a8d5/examples/worker-pool.php).

Comment: Seems like it is only compatible with PHP 7.0 or higher? Any possibilities I can use for lower PHP version maybe V 5.0x ?

Comment: @ShyamBhimani PHP 5.0, seriously? That has been released in 2004. PHP 5.x is out of active support and won't receive any bug fixes anymore. Consider upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

`php name_of_script.php &>/dev/null &`

this line will start your script in the background.
I suppose you do not want to control a critical process like sending mails from your browser? What if your connection breaks a few seconds?

If so: still use command line approach, but using exec

`$command = '/usr/bin/php path/to/script.php & echo $!');`